# How can I update the font inside mat-dialogs only (angular 8)?

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular8

I have tried this however it only updates some of the text inside mat-dialogs:

_mat-typography-overrides.scss:

```
@import '../node_modules/@angular/material/theming';

$custom-typography: map-merge(
  mat-typography-config(),
  mat-typography-config(
    $font-family: 'Exo-2',
  )
);

@mixin mat-typography-overrides() {
  .mat-dialog-container {
    @include angular-material-typography($custom-typography);
  }
}
```

Then I include the file in my theme:
    @include mat-typography-overrides();

Button text updates to Exo-2 however spans and hrefs remain the default font.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because font-family doesn't get applied to standard elements the same way it does to components. You need to apply it as part of your custom selector:

```
@mixin mat-typography-overrides() {
  .mat-dialog-container {
    font-family: 'Exo-2';
    @include angular-material-typography($custom-typography);
  }
}
```

See https://material.angular.io/guide/typography#material-typography-in-your-custom-css (last example).